# C# SQL DataGridView change field before updating database

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a WindowsForms app with a DataGridView bound to a SQL database. All columns except one ("ts_last_edit") are editable.
I want to update the "ts_last_edit" column only programmatically with the current DateTime every time someone changes some of the other columns AND saves the changes.
I tried this:

```
...
    this.MyTableAdapter.Adapter.RowUpdating += Adapter_RowUpdating;
...
private void Adapter_RowUpdating(object sender, SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
  e.Row["ts_last_edit"]=DateTime.Now;    
}
```

But it did not work because e.Row is a read-only property apparently.

I tried changing the UPDATE SQL command and it works:

```
private void Adapter_RowUpdating(object sender, SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
// pseudo code
string newSqlCommand= "STUFF CURRENT DATE AND TIME IN COLUMN ts_last_edit";
e.Command.CommandText = newSqlCommand;
}
```

This works OK, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.
Thank you

Comment: `But it did not work because e.Row is a read-only property apparently.` What **exact** exception was thrown?

Comment: you need to update the value in row_leave event

Comment: @njwills No exception thrown. But no change either.

Comment: @Krishna I want to store the DateTime when row is saved to database, not when a row loses focus

Comment: At what point you save it to database ? not on row leave ? do you have a button ? if so do it there

Comment: @Krishna, Yes I have a button. I may employ this solution, getting the dataset changes in the button handler and then storing the timestamp.

Comment: that will work as you have more control over there than in updating event

Comment: @Krishna Just tried, it does not work. In the button event I get the changed row but only as a copy, so when I write in it the current DateTime, it does not go to the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148503/discussion-between-krishna-and-user1523271).

Comment: This is the solution:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to merge changes back to dataset after updating the time

```
private void brandBookBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Validate();
  var changes = dataSet1.GetChanges();
  if(changes!=null && changes.Tables["BrandBook"].Rows.Count>0)
  {
    foreach(row in changes.Tables["BrandBook"].Rows)
    {
      row["ts_last_edit"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
  }
  dataSet1.Merge(changes, false,System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Add);
  this.brandBookBindingSource.EndEdit();
  this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.dataSet1);
}
```